# Using compatibility layer from Eclipse 3.8 to 4.x

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, e4

I have an Eclipse 3.x plugin which has a product file through which I launch the application. The product uses the eclipse workbench for its application parameter `org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench` and I even tried `org.eclipse.ui.e4.workbench.E4Application`.

I followed the steps of adding `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` and the `org.eclipse.emf.common` features in my product Dependencies as outlined in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html).

When I launch the application, it starts up and seems to work fine but there is no look and feel of E4 and some E4 features like the Theme preference under General-> Appearance in the Preferences menu does not work.

Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made it work by adding the following things in my org.eclipse.core.runtime.products extension,

```
<property
    name="cssTheme"
    value="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_default">
</property>
<property
    name="applicationCSSResources"
    value="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.platform/images/">
</property>
```

I don't know if this is the proper way of doing it so I am open to suggestions.