# Eclipse 3.x to E4 uplift. Could not start styling support...A null service reference is not allowed

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, e4

We have an RCP application that is running on the Eclipse 3.x platform and we're working on migrating it to pure E4 in the future. But just for now we're trying to pull in all the necessary dependencies. The app complies and runs but we get this stack trace at startup.

`!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2016-03-15 14:34:36.241
!MESSAGE Could not start styling support.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException: A null service reference is not allowed.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.BootstrapTheme3x.<init>(BootstrapTheme3x.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.BootstrapTheme3x.<init>(BootstrapTheme3x.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2532)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)`

There is one [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vogella/ZoXgdWT9EFk) out in the wild with a similar problem, but it's pretty out dated at this point.

Any help would be very appreciated!

**Update** I've tried out [link](http://www.programering.com/q/MDM4YzMwATA.html) which seems to be a similar issue. But that didn't fix it. I'm also wondering at this point if I have to many dependencies, and one is causing a conflict.

Comment: Yes it's RCP, we do have a product file for it. Using maven or eclipse to build the product generates the same stack trace at run time. As far as I know I've pulled in all the required dependencies. Besides that everything works as expected and is styled correctly.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is problems with start levels - are you specifying anything other than the defaults?

Comment: No we haven't specified any defaults, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Eclipse is this? The line numbers don't seem to correspond to the current Eclipse Mars - I would strongly advise using Mars rather than anything older.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after research I came across another post with a similar issue.
I implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836748/using-compatibility-layer-from-eclipse-3-8-to-4-x) and it solved my problem.